# Highlight collection cell when selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to highlight a selected collection cell in UICollectionView with yellow border so user can see which one is currently selected. I tried this:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FilterCell *filterCell = (FilterCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"FilterCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    filterCell.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    filterCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    NSLog(@"hello");
}
```

There are 2 empty pixels around UIImageView inside UICollectionViewCell so it should work but it doesn't.

It is logging "hello" but the border stays black. See this screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are getting the cell in the wrong way

```
FilterCell *filterCell = (FilterCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"FilterCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

will dequeue a cell which is not used right now or allocate a new one with the specified identifier.

Use

```
FilterCell *filterCell = (FilterCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

instead.

Anyway a cleaner solution would be to set the `backgroundView` and `selectedBackgroundView` properties of the cell, without touching the `backgroundProperty` color (that will stay `clear` as default). In this way you can avoid the delegate method and achieve the same behavior.

Comment: Hmm.  This is a good answer.  I can't decide whether I like it better than mine or not.  Will be interested to see what others think.  In my last collection view, I altered the selected cell's size, which favors my approach, I think; on the other hand, this idea is more of a straight line, and more directly related to the OP's issue.

Comment: if you change the size of the cell, the `backgroundView` and the `selectedBackgroundView` will be scaled accordingly. In case of a uniform color background view everything would work just fine with this approach ;)

Comment: Yeah?  I'm convinced.  +1.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Do a `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths`: there instead, then in cellForItemAtIndexPath, check if  `[[collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] containsObject:indexPath]` If true, change the cell's attributes there.

Comment: Hi, do this work for visible cells too? I'm trying to assign an image if the cell is visible with:

if ([[collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems] containsObject:indexPath]){
        imageView.image = [gridImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

But it's not working.  This condition is never true.

Comment: It should work for any selection.  NSLog both your indexPath and the indexPathsForVisibleItems (both can be seen with %@ in the format string).

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR_FILE_NAME.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

-This code may help you to change background colour of selected cell

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView    cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell.selected) {
 cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; // highlight selection 
}
else
{
 cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // Default color
}
return cell;
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {

UICollectionViewCell *datasetCell =[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
datasetCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; // highlight selection
}  
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UICollectionViewCell *datasetCell =[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
datasetCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // Default color
}
```